# Hibernate create Relations with Entiies

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I'm having trouble creating some simple relations between my entities and list of entities.

I tried this.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "START_ID")
private OneEntity e1;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "END_ID")
private OneEntity e2;

@ElementCollection
private List<OneEntity > set = new ArrayList<>();
```

My database looks like this with these columns:

`START_ID`, `END_ID` are entities and the LIST is just a list of my entities.

```
 ID | START_ID | END_ID | LIST_ID     &&     ID | ENTITY_ID
```

`START_ID` and `END_ID` are created as simple foreign keys. These can also duplicates in different rows.

But when adding entities to the list which are already persisted, I got a MySQL exception.

> org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Duplicate entry '7' for key 'UK_3j2pbjj67dh0dcx3hgwwf1wo7'

Which means I cant persist the same entity in my list.

How can I accomplish such logic in MySQL database? (ofc without crashes lol)

Comment: How is there a relation "set" with `@ElementCollection` when `OneEntity` is presumably an entity? `@ElementCollection` is for non-entities! How can anyone comment on your persistence of objects when you don't present the CODE for persistence of objects (where you set up relations, and call persist) ?

Comment: Okay thanks.Good to know that  '@ElementCollection' cant have entities. It kinda works in hibernate but wont allow duplicate entries (which is my problem). In the example above OneEntity is a refence to the Entity in my DB. But I want to save list of refences to those entities. How to accomplish this and allow duplicate refences to those entities.